# How do I download a Debian ARM package from another computer

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, apt, arm

I am trying to use apt-get to install some packages on an offline system.

I have a small ARM embedded system running Debian. It is not connected to the internet. I would like to download some Debian packages from another Linux machine that is connected to the Internet using apt-get.

There are several aspects here:

(1) I would like to download from the ARM Architecture Debian (Jessie) repository.

(2) I would like to do that from my x86 Linux system.

(3) I would like to save those packages in a directory of my choice (I don't want them co-mingled with my default package cache) and then move these files to my Debian ARM system.

How do I do this?

<<

Comment: Download packages from https://packages.debian.org/jwheezy/ ... Or use the "Search" e.g.  here https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ed .... Look for the line with e.g. armhf or arm64, click "arm..", and you will come to a page with links ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It firstly must be noted that what you wish to do is not at all recommended. The reason for this is that the package you need may require additional files updated or newly installed (also referred to as dependencies) to work without error.

The whole point of apt-get is that it is a package manager. In other words, it *purposefully* co-mingles the packages (AND its dependencies) exactly where they should be to run correctly on the local machine. This is a core way in which Linux operates differently than Windows.

Additionally as your host machine is in x86 and the offline machine arm64 you would have another potential issue using the correct install method for the host mahine.

To achieve what you desire, you would need to use another method, BUT this may introduce problems. Please be aware.

One such method would be to save to a usb to put into another device.

As you have specifically asked for Debian Jessie and ARM architecture the following should work for you. Head to [Debian Jessie arm64 Packages](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/arm64/) to BROWSE the full list of packages (or [SEARCH here](https://packages.debian.org/index)). When you locate the package you need, the bottom of its listing will have a link for all available architectures. If you used the browse link I provided it will only show arm64 packages.

Note that here you will see all the dependencies and begin to appreciate how awesome apt-get is. If your offline machine is missing **even one** of these dependencies the installation will fail. Obtaining the appropriate dependencies might turn into a rabbit trail.

Assuming you have the required dependencies already or you live in a magic walled garden:

Click on arm64 >> then the mirror site closest to you >> save to your desired location.

You can transfer the package to your offline machine. To install on that machine from terminal `$ dpkg -i <your_file.deb>` and you *could* be good to go. And it's at this point you're likely to hit problems if any dependencies are missing. If you still wish to proceed you would need to perform a 'force install'.

Comment: I am revisiting this again, because I see the need for a decentralized apt-get. I will look into this.